# Asp.net webforms - CausesValidation=true is being ignored

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have encountered a problem with a page we have, and have narrowed down a sample like so:

ASPX:

```
     <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSomething" runat="server" 
                     CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnFilter" runat="server" Text="Filter" />
    </div>
```

Code:

```
Partial Class ValTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFilter.Click

        BindGrid()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlSomething_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlSomething.SelectedIndexChanged

        BindGrid()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BindGrid()

        If (Page.IsValid) Then

            'Do something that takes a little time here
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

            Response.Write("Done")

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that the dropdown list has autopostback set to true and causesvalidation set to true.

Now, if I change the dropdown list and let the page load, it works without issue. Similarly, if I just click the button, then it works ok. However, if I change the dropdown list and then, before the page has totally reloaded, click the button, then I get this error:

***Page.IsValid cannot be called before validation has taken place. It should be queried in the event handler for a control that has CausesValidation=True and initiated the postback, or after a call to Page.Validate.***

Now, I can fix this by putting a `Page.Validate()` in front of my check for `Page.IsValid`, however I am curious if anybody can explain why this is happening.  I am expecting two postbacks to have been sent, each causing validation, and each should have worked...

---

ASP.net 4.5, just in case it makes a difference.